# Classlist toggle on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, dry

I have functioning code, but I am sure there is a way to write it cleaner.

My code is far from best practice I assume. Don't repeat yourself principle.

I have tried looking for this problem but can not find an answer.

Here are the expected result and my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ednsp6x/

```
document.getElementById("BtnMoreTotalt").onclick = function() {MoreBtnTotalt()};
function MoreBtnTotalt() {
    document.querySelector(".more-wrapper-totalt").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

I also wonder, if there is a way so I do not have to use specific id and classnames on every element? Could I only use class "more-wrapper" and skip the IDs?

Comment: You can replace `function() {MoreBtnTotalt()}` with `MoreBtnTotalt`. In general, you can write a function where each clicked element determines the other element. The easiest way is to give them a common parent. Let me edit your fiddle.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/u97j4b0h/

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice solution, however it forces me to change my html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".more-button").forEach(element => {
  element.onclick = (e) => {
    const elm = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.getAttribute("anchor"));
    elm[0].classList.toggle("show");
  };
});
```

```css
.more-wrapper {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.more-wrapper.show {visibility:visible};
```

```html
<div class="more-wrapper more-wrapper-totalt">
  <div>test1</div>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">
  <div anchor="more-wrapper-totalt" class="more-button">Mer info</div>
</a>

<div class="more-wrapper more-wrapper-kvant">
  <div>test2</div>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">
  <div anchor="more-wrapper-kvant" class="more-button">Mer info</div>
</a>

<div class="more-wrapper more-wrapper-invb">
  <div>test3</div>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">
  <div anchor="more-wrapper-invb" class="more-button">Mer info</div>
</a>

<div class="more-wrapper more-wrapper-barn">
  <div>test4</div>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">
  <div anchor="more-wrapper-barn" class="more-button">Mer info</div>
</a>
```

You can add the className button with attribute after use this attr click event. It's like clone but i think you need this class another place.

Comment: If you don't want this solution, you should be change your HTML structure.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have your example with a re-usable button click handler.

To make it work, you have to:

- Wrap all your groups of button/content in a wrapper div with a class
- Change the CSS so it works over the wrappers class
- Add the click event handler to every element of the class
- Use the event to get the nearest wrapper
- now you can change the class of it

```js
// Query through all "a" elements that are inside a ".wrapper" element
document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > a").forEach(b => {
  // Add a click handler to each
  b.onclick = (e) => {
    // prevent the default action of an "a" element
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the closest wrapper from the event
    let button = e.target;
    let wrapper = button.closest(".wrapper");

    // now change the class
    wrapper.classList.toggle("show");
  };
});
```

```css
.wrapper > div {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.wrapper.show > div {
  visibility:visible
};
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>test1</div>
  <a href="#">Mer info</a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>test2</div>
  <a href="#">Mer info</a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>test3</div>
  <a href="#">Mer info</a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>test4</div>
  <a href="#">Mer info</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Code has multiple identical `id`s and doesn't work for the last three links.

Comment: @ChrisG My mistake, fixed it!