# How to console log the text from an input when pressing the button associated with it?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, submit

I am new to Angular (it's actually my third day, with some semi-consistent prior JS knowledge) and I'm a little confused about how to console.log the text that the user writes in the input box when pressing the submit button next to it.

I know the answer to this question should be found in any part of the internet, but I didn't find it by googling in multiple ways.

TS part of the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-boxes',
  templateUrl: './input-boxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-boxes.component.css']
})
export class InputBoxesComponent {
  onClick(){
    console.log();
  }
}
```

HTML part of the component:

```
<div class="first-row">

    <div class="input-button">   

        <mat-form-field class="input">
            <input matInput placeholder="Text">
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="button" (click)="onClick()">
            <button mat-raised-button class='submit-button'>Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="input-button">

        <mat-form-field class="input">
            <input matInput placeholder="Text">
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="button">
            <button mat-raised-button class='submit-button'>Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS part of the component:

```
.first-row {
    display: flex;
    width: 66%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.input-button {
    display: flex;
    width: 45%;
}

.mat-raised-button {
    background-color: #FFC200;
    color: black;
}

.input {
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I managed to get the button to console log anything, but i don't know how to associate it with the text from the input.

Comment: have you explored about ngModel?

Comment: Yesterday I wrote an answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589793/classlist-toggle-on-multiple-elements/57589934#57589934 Might help you. In the example it toggles the class of the element near to it. In your case you just have to read the `.value` of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `ngModel` in Angular.

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-boxes',
  templateUrl: './input-boxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-boxes.component.css']
})
export class InputBoxesComponent {
  public text: string;
  onClick(){
    console.log(this.text);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input matInput placeholder="Text"
      [(ngModel)]="text">
```

To use ngModel you have to import FormsModule package in app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
             FormsModule      
        ]
```

Basically, ngModel is used to bind value from the respective HTML element. ngModel is mostly used on template-driven forms. If you have more than two inputs you can use reactive forms.

Comment: I used this option and it shows me this: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
        
        <mat-form-field class="input">
            <input matInput [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="text" placeholder="Text">
        </mat-form-field>.

Comment: Imported formsmodule to app module. Now it works! Ty.

Comment: @Alexandru-MarianConstantin I have updated the answer. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to do this is by adding a template reference variable if you don't want to use template driven/reactive forms:

```
<mat-form-field class="input">
    <input matInput placeholder="Text" #input>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="button" (click)="onClick(input.value)">
    <button mat-raised-button class='submit-button'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

In the component:

```
onClick(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it will be better to keep the `(click)` event in the button element instead of keeping it in the parent `div` element.

We can do this in many ways. It completely depends on how you want to do it.
First you can use a template variable to pass the value of input to the click function.

Component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-boxes',
  templateUrl: './input-boxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-boxes.component.css']
})
export class InputBoxesComponent {
  onClick(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field class="input">
  <input matInput placeholder="Text" #inputText>
</mat-form-field>
<div class="button" (click)="onClick(inputText.value)">
  <button mat-raised-button class='submit-button'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Second way is to use ViewChild and ElementRef from angular/core

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-input-boxes',
   templateUrl: './input-boxes.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./input-boxes.component.css']
})
export class InputBoxesComponent {
     @ViewChild("inputText")input: ElementRef
     onClick(){
         console.log(this.input.value);
     }
 }
```

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field class="input">
    <input matInput placeholder="Text" #inputText>
</mat-form-field>
<div class="button" (click)="onClick()">
   <button mat-raised-button class='submit-button'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

This is how we can simply print. If you are using any forms, it can vary based on the type of form we are using.

Answer (score 0):

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgg96i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The following code will help you trigger whenever value changes

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" (ngModelChange)="onTyping(username)">


  onTyping($event){
    console.log($event)
  }
```

Or by simply

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username">
<button (click)="onClick()">Click me</button>
```

you can get value from variable

```
onClick(){
 console.log(this.username)
}
```